# Livewire Flash Message HTML tag working SCRIPT not

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have a livewire component with a function of session flash but it is not working accordingly.

```
    @if(session('alert'))
       <h6>alert</h6>
       <script>
       console.log('test');
       </script>
    @endif
```

I can see the H6 tag in my page but the script is not working.

I tried re-arranging my JS, CSS and livewireScript. All I can see is the h6 tag.

Tried adding dispatch, still not working.

***Edit***
This does work when added a $this->redirect() method, but is there a way to flash a message without reloading the page or redirecting to other page?

Comment: When the code fragment is sent via *AJAX* request, the JS code is ignored by the browser

Comment: Comment on '**Modify**': *redirect()* loads a new page and then the JS is evaluated.
Since you are using Livewire, there may be a workaround, perhaps using custom events and including some Alpine code, but the posted code is too little to formulate a precise answer

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my code, i noticed that i am using livewire 3 instead of 2, then i tried to install livewire 2 using `composer require livewire/livewire:^2.0` but it return an error

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires livewire/livewire 2.0 -> satisfiable by livewire/livewire[v2.0.0].
    - livewire/livewire v2.0.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Then i tried `composer require livewire/livewire:^2.12.6` this is the latest in 2.X.

added a listener and emit in my function, it works!